# Get all Html content from given url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a application in asp.net and I want to make a feature where I can get all the html content from given url.

like if I put the link www.stackoverflow.com

It give the whole content of stackoverflow. Is it possible to make this feature in asp.net.

If, Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to ways to do this..

First

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://stackoverflow.com");

using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using(var content = response.GetResponseStream())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(content)){
    var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Second

```
var result = string.Empty;
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    result = webClient.DownloadString("http://some.url");
}
```

Hope this will help you